# Installing scrapy/pyopenssl in Windows' virtualenv

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv, scrapy, pyopenssl

I am trying to [install scrapy](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.14/intro/install.html) on Windows XP (32bit) virtualenv:

```
pip install scrapy
```

The installer spits out this ambiguous error message:

```
error: Only found improper OpenSSL directories: ['E:\\cygwin', 'E:\\Program Files\\Git']
```

How should I configure openssl / pyOpenSSL to make pip work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Apparently pyopenssl installation expects the binaries and libs to be laid out exactly as installed by [OpenSSL windows binaries](http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html).  Installing it from there (and not using cygwin's openssl for example), and adding the bin directory to the path solved this issue.

Comment: Note: Need to install the regular version of OpenSSL, not the 'light' version that's first in the list!

Comment: For those of you getting an error about SSL timing out, this solution worked for me.  I had to install the Visual C++ 2008 Redistributables (which corrected that error, and then gave me the error from this question), and then install the actual OpenSSL binary.

Answer (score 3):

Installing the newest package from that site with the default settings didn't work me. It seems to look for `openssl.exe` in your PATH and then look for the libraries in its parent directory. A quick fix is to find wherever openssl.exe got installed and add the directory to your path. For me it was:

```
set path=%path%;C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the following problem trying to install pyOpenSSL using pip: `Setup script exited with error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat`

After updating the setuptools (`pip install -U setuptools`), the pip install worked. I did not have to install any binaries manually.